# Share RPD/Vnc but not internet

Tags: ubuntu, routing, rdp, vnc

My headless Ubuntu box has 2 ethernet ports. One is connected to the internet. The other I would like to use to share vnc/rdp to a Macintosh but **not** allow the Macintosh to reach the internet nor be reachable from the internet.  So the macintosh is technically not internet connected but can access the internet via rdp with the Ubuntu server.  How do I configure this on Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! This site is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Your question appears to be [out of scope for this site](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Your question may be more appropriate for Super User, Ask Ubuntu or Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Research how to set up a Ubuntu system as a router.  Then don't do that.

Research how to set up IPtables.  Allow RDP and VNC on local interface.  Disallow it (and more) on internet interface.

Of course if it is a newer version of Ubuntu, you may be using systemd, which replaces IPTables, and I'm not familiar with the name of the replacement.

Edit:  systemd uses Firewalld as its firewall.

Comment: When you talk about a replacement for `iptables` do you mean `ip6tables`?